# No share actions available when using subclassed UIActivityItemProvider

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I just pass in an NSString, everything works perfectly, but when I try to pass in my custom ItemProvider I get no share actions available.

**MyCustomProvider**

```
class MyCustomProvider: UIActivityItemProvider {

    var placeholder: String!
    var alternate: String!


    init(placeholder: String, alternate: String) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.alternate = alternate

        super.init()
    }

    override func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
            return NSString(string: alternate)
        } else {
            return NSString(string: placeholder)
        }
    }
}
```

**Where I execute:**

```
var stringToShare = MyCustomProvider(placeholder: "Placeholder", alternate: "Alternate")

var sharingItems = [AnyObject]()
sharingItems.append(stringToShare)

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypeAirDrop]

self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When stringToShare above instead is `NSString(string: "Placeholder")`, everything works perfectly. What did I mess up in my implementation?

Comment: I've tried many things. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by instead doing the following:

```
class MyCustomProvider: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

    var placeholder: String!
    var alternate: String!


    init(placeholder: String, alternate: String) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.alternate = alternate

        super.init()
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return NSString(string: placeholder)
    }

    func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
            return NSString(string: alternate)
        } else {
            return NSString(string: placeholder)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe you must set the placeholderItem to the type you are going to return in item().

> An object that can stand in for the actual object you plan to create. The contents of the object may be empty but the class of the object must match the class of the object you plan to provide later.